# MacBook Pro Won't Boot on power on but does eventually

Tags: macbook-pro

I've got a 2012 MacBook Pro which, when you turn it on, shows the no drive icon.

But if you leave it for about 5 minutes or so, it starts to boot and works normally.

The hard drive has been changed and it's still doing it. Memory has also been swapped and tested

A Hardware test came back saying "No Issues"

Could the hard drive cable cause this issue or am I looking at the logical board.

Thanks

Comment: It's entirely possible that the SATA cable is the issue; it's also a common issue with these particular models.

Comment: i googled on "2012 MacBook Pro sata cable issue" and found many links related to this issue.  Most of the links referred to problems with the cable.